# Abstraction and Spring - Multiple children

Tags: java, spring, abstraction

I'm trying to make a Web Aplication with Spring, and my classes (Controllers and Services) are using Abstraction to avoid code repetition. Knowing that, this is my structure:

```
public abstract class AbstractController {
    @Autowired
    private AbstractService serviceAbs;
    .
    .
    .
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/webService")
public class Service1Controller extends AbstractController {
    @Autowired
    Service1Service service;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "..." })
    public final ModelAndView addService(...) {
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class AbstractService {
    @Autowired
    protected ServiceDAO serviceDAO;

    public final ModelAndView addService(...) {
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

@Service
public class Service1Service extends AbstractService {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This works fine, but when I try to add another child to the AbstractService, the Spring can't work, even when I use Qualifier anotation, I don't know what to do anymore. (I'm learning English yet, so sorry for any mistakes)

Comment: You need to add `@Primary` annotation in one of sub classes

Comment: remove the @Service on the abstract service

Comment: Why would `AbstractService` be a `@Service` service??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I need to make a generic instance of the abstract class, and then use the Qualifier annotation, so I created:

```
@Service
public class GenericService extends AbstractServiceService {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And then, at the abstractController I change the propertie:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("genericService")
private AbstractService serviceAbs;
```

Thanks to Basil Battikhi, his sugestion did make me seach about some other annotations.